# call sql query in lable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Please help me,I write this code but it doesn't work what is my mistake and what is the correct code ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(Class1.CnnStr);

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(Code) FROM Customer";

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Code_lbl.Text,"@MAX(Code)"+1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: wow. what is your intention over there?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx). Also you should properly dispose IDisposable resources such as sql connections and sql commands by wrapping them in using statements:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Class1.CnnStr))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(Code) FROM Customer";
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't receive parameters and you are passing one.

Also yo don't do ExecuteNonQuery in this case. ExecuteNonQuery is for statements that insert or modify data but your statement simply returns a single value. What you need is  ExecuteScalar, which returns a single result from your query.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Class1.CnnStr))
{
  conn.Open();
  using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Code) FROM Customer",conn))
  {
    cmd.Connection.Open();  
    int max = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse parameter, do like below

```
    string commandText = "SELECT MAX(Code) FROM Customer WHERE ShopID = @ID;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id); // e.g id is int = 23;

        try
        {
          connection.Open();
          var maxCode= command.ExecuteScalar();
          Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}", maxCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```